# Nested select MAX() of another table when data doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: Post, Community, and Community Moderator. I created an SQL query to show the communities a user moderates, including date created, and date updated. Date updated is calculated according to the MAX created date of a post in that community.

Here is the code that works for communities that have posts:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.created, p.created as 'postdate'
FROM Post p, Community c, CommunityMod cm
WHERE p.created in
    (
        SELECT MAX(created)
        FROM Post
        GROUP BY community
    )
AND cm.moderator=$id AND p.community=c.id AND cm.community=c.id
ORDER by c.created DESC
```

The problem is that this query will not select communities without any posts since there is no data in p.community.

I would like it to also show the communities without any posts, but instead of p.created for the updated information, it would show nothing or the date the community was created (c.created) instead.
How would I do that?

Comment: Why are you joining the `CommunityMod` if you don't use it anywhere?

Comment: Because I need to select a particular moderator using cm.moderator=$id

Comment: Missed that - my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN for the `Post` table. Note that all conditions on columns from the `Post` table should be placed into the ON clause.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Community c
JOIN CommunityMod cm ON cm.community = c.id
LEFT JOIN Post p
  ON  p.community = c.id
  AND p.created in
    (
        SELECT MAX(created)
        FROM Post
        GROUP BY community
    )
WHERE cm.moderator = $id
ORDER by c.created DESC
```

Note that your subquery might not work as expected, ff `Post.created` is not UNIQUE. You should change it to a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Community c
JOIN CommunityMod cm ON cm.community = c.id
LEFT JOIN Post p
  ON  p.community = c.id
  AND p.created in
    (
        SELECT MAX(p1.created)
        FROM Post p1
        WHERE p1.community = c.id
    )
WHERE cm.moderator = $id
ORDER by c.created DESC
```

However - If you only need the `created` value from the `Post` table, then you don't need a subquery at all.

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.created, MAX(p.created) as 'postdate'
FROM Community c
JOIN CommunityMod cm ON cm.community = c.id
LEFT JOIN Post p ON p.community = c.id
WHERE cm.moderator = $id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER by c.created DESC
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised I'd somehow left out the SELECT statement of the original query so I've edited it back in. I did get your query to work. Thank you so much!